# svg - угол не острый, как ожидалось

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

Когда я пытаюсь нарисовать фигуру с помощью SVG, углы выглядят не острыми, как ожидалось. Правый угол выглядит потрясающе, но два других не выглядят острыми.

Я использую d3.js, чтобы нарисовать его:

```js
var width = 600
  var height = 600
  var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width',width)
  .attr('height',height)
  //.style('border','1px solid red')
  .attr('viewBox',`0 0 15 15`)

  var g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('fill','none')
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('stroke-width',1)
  
  var path = ['M',10,6,2,2,5,6,2,10,'z'].join(' ')
   g.append('path')
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [svg - corner not sharp as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68041335/7394871) от участника  [@lucky1928](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1914781/lucky1928).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68041335/7394871

Answer (score 5):

Этим управляет свойство [stroke-miterlimit](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#StrokeProperties). Его значение по умолчанию - 4, но вы можете использовать большее значение, если это соответствует тому, что вы хотите.

```js
var width = 600
  var height = 600
  var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width',width)
  .attr('height',height)
  //.style('border','1px solid red')
  .attr('viewBox',`0 0 15 15`)

  var g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('fill','none')
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('stroke-width',1)
  
  var path = ['M',10,6,2,2,5,6,2,10,'z'].join(' ')
   g.append('path')
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('stroke-miterlimit', 10)
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68041521/7394871) от участника  [@Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson).</sub>

Comment: Хоть кто-то делом занят)) Спасибо, что вы есть!!!

Comment: @Leonid  Благодарю. Вот всё жду, когда вы зададите и оформите свой первый вопрос по SVG. Год назад вы вроде заинтересовались этой темой. Или мне это показалось? :)  С удовольствием поучаствую в ответах

Comment: Вопросов много, пока накачал книг. Сначала надо хоть JS вспомнить, а потом уже Canvas + SVG. Есть некоторые задумки)) Буду оформлять вопросы, обязательно. Буду ваши материалы смотреть, накопилось наверняка))

Comment: @Leonid чтобы желание не отбить, начните с простого - анимация простых объектов. В SVG анимация, наряду с фильтрами, - это самый мощный раздел. css и canvas очень сильно проигрывают, не дотягивают в этих разделах до возможностей SVG.